# How to print the text that is included in three tags only?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping a website and I'm stuck at one part. I'm trying to print only text that is included in three HTML tags.

Here is a small example of what I am scraping.

```
<h3>This is a header</h3>
<b>NOTE:</b> Important note that I don't need!<br><br>
<TABLE  width="100%" cellpadding="2">
<TR>
<TD COLSPAN="18" class = "subject_header">Also another thing that I don't need</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD COLSPAN="18" class="Data"><br><font size=2 ><b>***THIS IS THE TEXT THAT I REALLY NEED!!!*** </b></font><BR> <p><b>Note: </b><i> And more text that I don't need </i></p> Some other text that I don't care about</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD COLSPAN="5"><b><font color="red">And more stuff I don't need</font></b></TD>
<TD COLSPAN="18" class="Data"><br><font size=2 >Text that I don't need. </TD>
</TR>
```

The text that I am really needing to extract is...

```
<TD COLSPAN="18" class="Data"><br><font size=2 ><b>THIS IS THE TEXT THAT I REALLY NEED!!! </b></font>
```

I have tried many things but everything I try I get all the text instead of just that.

----------EDIT----------

I forgot to write that the html file contains many lines with the same class, so if I try to use

```
soup.find_all("td", {"class":"Data"})
```

it would not work.

Also updated the html code to show an example of what I mean. Notice that the one I'm trying to get has the bold tag (I'm pretty sure that that will help).

Comment: Try to post the code which you've writed. So we can help you

Comment: Have tried getting text by `class`?

Comment: Hello thanks for the comments!! 
I just updated the code to show that I did try getting the text by class. The only issue is that that is not the only part of the html code that has the same class.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your code something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(your_html_object, "html.parser")
td = soup.find('td', {'class': "Data"})
print(td.b.text)
```

Result:

```
*** THIS IS THE TEXT THAT I REALLY NEED!!!***
```

Comment: Hello thank you for the comment! In the original post I did not type in all the  code and missed a big part of the issue. I did just update the code to show what I mean.
The html code has more than one line that contains the same class but I only want the lines that also contain the bold tag and the font size=2.

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html ='''<h3>This is a header</h3>
<b>NOTE:</b> Important note that I don't need!<br><br>
<TABLE  width="100%" cellpadding="2">
<TR>
<TD COLSPAN="18" class = "subject_header">Also another thing that I don't need</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD COLSPAN="18" class="Data"><br><font size=2 ><b>***THIS IS THE TEXT THAT I REALLY NEED!!!*** </b></font><BR> <p><b>Note: </b><i> And more text that I don't need </i></p> Some other text that I don't care about</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD COLSPAN="5"><b><font color="red">And more stuff I don't need</font></b></TD>
</TR>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
text = soup.find('td', class_='Data').b.text
print(text)
```

**Output**

```
***THIS IS THE TEXT THAT I REALLY NEED!!!***
```

Answer (score 0):

One more, a little bit more concise option - use a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select_one("td.Data b").text
```

---

If there are multiple elements matching a locator and you want to get all of them:

```
[elm.text for elm in soup.select("td.Data b")]
```